# Agda PDFs with colour

Tags: pdf, syntax-highlighting, agda, literate-programming

I am using lhs2TeX for my literate Agda files and I'd like them to be syntax highlighted. I know I can achieve some highlighting via `%format` instructions but that is a bit too much. I have tried using lhs2Tex-hl as instructed at http://foswiki.cs.uu.nl/foswiki/pub/FPOld/CourseLiterature/presentation.pdf but to no avail.

If anyone can help with getting PDF's with coloured Agda, that'd be appreciated!

**Edit**

The Agda latex backend is great but has some issues. Biggest issue is spec-environment. It says that spec is undefined, so making it a synonym for `code` should fix things: `\newenvironment{spec}{\begin{code}}{\end{code}}`, but instead now there are type-checking issues and `missing $` errors. Using sed to remove spec blocks altogether results in `missing $` errors; likewise `\newenvironment{spec}{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}`. Similar trouble with using `|...|`. Also, I honestly liked the `%format` of lhs2tex ...

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the latex backend? http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.LiterateAgda

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the backend!